# How can I add a preconfigured/template Xcode breakpoint?

Tags: xcode, debugging, breakpoints

About 80% of the time, when I add an Xcode breakpoint I want it to have:

- An action of "Log Message"
- The text of "%B %H" to print to the console when it's encountered
- The "Automatically continue" checkbox checked

Setting this up is possible, but tedious. I know that you can create a breakpoint like this in LLDB using a `breakpoint set` command, which I could alias. However, I believe that this would require the debugger to be running and paused. It also forgets the breakpoint when the process ends, and doesn't show up in Xcode.

What I'd really like is to be able to run a script via a keyboard command from within Xcode to set my template breakpoint on the current line.

Is there any way to do this?